# Breast cancer Dataset high loss function and low accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

i am new to the ml topic and tried some training today. I ran into several problems until i reached the position where i am now. Can anyone explane to me why the accurcy is not changing and why the loss function is so high? I used the wisconsin breast cancer data set.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',)

df['diagnosis']=df['diagnosis'].replace(['M'], 1)
df['diagnosis']=df['diagnosis'].replace(['B'], 0)

df = df.iloc[: , :-1]

df.head

x = df.drop(columns=["diagnosis"])

y = df["diagnosis"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

df.dtypes

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500)
```

Comment: Hi, I try copy&paste your code but using `from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer` dataset and seams working. I am getting accuracy of 0.96 and loss of 0.07 which is not bad. Maybe 500 are too much epocs for this genre of problem. Anyway, could you please share the links of the data you are using?. Moreover, could you please provide more info on the column you are removing here `df = df.iloc[: , :-1]`? Maybe it is an important one

Comment: @AndreaIerardiv thanks for your quick reply. Yeah thats pretty good. I also expected results in this range. I also tried it with less epochs but there was basically no change in accuracy ... I used this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data
I removed the last column from the datafram because it was empty and i had the problem that the lossfunction was NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Kaggle dataset you provide in the question comments, I run the model again. I faced the same problem you were describing:

```
Epoch 500/500
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6577 - accuracy: 0.6328
```

The reason is that in the dataset is present the column `id`. Drop this column before training phase:

```
df = df.drop('id', axis=1)
```

I obtained better results:

```
Epoch 500/500
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0770 -  accuracy: 0.9648
```

(almost) Always remove IDs and identifiers columns from your dataset. If you need it, set it as the index of the dataframe but not as column. They confused the predictor in training phase since they do not provide any useful information.